# composer update is not downloading anything

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony5, symfony5.4

In a Symfony 5.4 project calling

```
composer update
```

stops (or is not proceeding) when the downloading part should process.
It lists all the things to download like this

```
Downloading php-http/discovery (1.19.1)
Downloading symfony/flex (v1.20.2)
...
Downloading symfony/yaml (v5.4.23)
Downloading twig/extra-bundle (v3.7.0)
Downloading twig/string-extra (v3.7.0)
```

and then the line

```
0/82 [>---------------------------]   0%
```

stays like that forever not proceeding / changing.
Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running

```
composer diagnose
```

led me to the problem (yeah - I should have asked composer for that before...)
It told me

```
Checking github.com oauth access: The oauth token for github.com seems invalid, run "composer config --global --unset github-oauth.github.com" to remove it
```

Doing that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably composer tries to connect using http protocol. Try this to change the protocol to https:
`composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org`

Comment: thanks, tried that - but still not proceeding :-\ How would I check which connection composer uses? Or are there any other things to consider?